# imageNamed not working on iPhone 4 when using variable name for image

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am using imageNamed to set images in my app. The app correctly takes 2x images when specifying the image name i.e.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"]; //works fine on iPhone 4 and 3G(S)
```

But if I specify the image name in a variable, the 2x images are not picked up i.e.

```
NSString *imageNameVar = @"abc.png";
[UIImage imageNamed:imageNameVar]; //does not work
```

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the file extension `.png`?

Comment: Yes I have. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

try `NSString *imageNameVar =[NSString stringWithString:@"abc.png"];`